# Advanced Custom Field not showing in template

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm racking my brain trying to think why this isn't working. Seems to be right to me but I must be missing something.

```
<?php
    if( have_rows('cta_box') ):
        while( have_rows('cta_box') ) : the_row();
            echo get_sub_field('cta_header');
            echo get_sub_field('cta_content');
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Am I doing something dumb?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a group field, not repeater. [This'd](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/) help.

So in your case you'd use it like this.

```
$cta = get_field('cta_box');

echo $cta['cta_header'];
echo $cta ['cta_content];
```

Comment: Still nothing :S. I copied my code from that link you sent but still empty fields. var_dump of $cta is null also.

Comment: These are not the only fields on this page. Does that change anything?

Comment: It depends on so many things, are you tying to print this on a 'single' page? loop? Just pass the post id and it should print. Like this $cta = get_field('cta_box', 23); I'm adding the id manually here, but that's just an example. You'd get the ID either using $global post and then $post->ID or by get_the_ID() function.

Answer (score 0):

your code is proper, i think the issue is where you want to display like in the specific template or any where in the page, you just need to assign with the template or page or post whatever its will display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that got it working. Can someone explain? Is the code above this ACF effecting what is returned?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $cta = get_field('state_call_to_action');
    echo $cta['call_to_action_heading'];
    echo $cta['call_to_action_body'];
endwhile; ?>
```